# Issue while using ?: operator inside Array.prototype.findIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```js
var img = $('img');
var div = $('div');

var arr = ['1', '2', '3'];

console.log(arr.findIndex(x => x === img.length ? img.prop('id') : div.prop('id')));

console.log(arr.findIndex(x => x === (img.length ? img.prop('id') : div.prop('id'))));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="2"></div>
```

Output:

> 0
>
> 1

The first case:

```
x === img.length ? img.prop('id') : div.prop('id')
```

If it compared `x` to `img.length`. I don't understand that why did it return `0`?

`img.prop('id')` returns `undefined` and `div.prop('id')` returns `2`, why did it log `0`?

The second case:

```
x === (img.length ? img.prop('id') : div.prop('id'))
```

it got the id of the div tag before comparing to `x`. That's okay.

Please correct me. Thank you!

Comment: Your first case evaluates to `arr.findIndex(x => 2)`, which will always evaluate to *true* on the first iteration (index **0**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` will always be a string in your code, and `img.length` will be a number, so they will never be strictly equal (`===`).

So it gets evaluated as:

```
(x === img.length) ? img.prop('id') : div.prop('id')
(false           ) ? img.prop('id') : div.prop('id')
                                      div.prop('id')
                                      2
```

`findIndex` waits for a truthy value, and `div.prop('id')` is `2`, which is truthy. It returns this on the first index, which is why it returns 0.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested again by changing the id of the div to `0`, it logs `-1` for the result. Something like: if the condition is `true`, the first item in the array is match (no need to continue comparing `2` === `1`), otherwise, returning -1. Right?

Comment: Whichever iteration of the array returns true is the result.